# Convert Set of Set to List of List in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, set, hashset

```
List<List<Integer>> lst = new ArrayList<List<>>();
```

Suppose I have list of list declared above with name as lst and I have a set of set elements variable declared below. How can I put elements of this set into lst?

```
Set<Set<Integer>> set = new HashSet<Set<>>();
```

Comment: The second declaration doesn't make sense. You're trying to initialise a list variable with a hashset object.

Comment: This code doesn't compile... An HashSet cannot be assigned to a List

Comment: Your title says you want to convert a set of sets to a list of lists. But your question says you already have a list of lists.

Comment: I have all the elements in a set which is Set<Set<Integer>> set. I have to put all these elements into the list lst.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you have a set of sets:

```java
Set<Set<Integer>> setOfSets = new HashSet<>();
```

To convert it into list of lists:

```java
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
```

Do the following:

```java
for (Set<Integer> set : setOfSets) {
    listOfLists.add(new ArrayList<>(set));
}
```

When you pass any collection to the ArrayList constructor, it creates a new ArrayList with all elements from this collection. In other words, `new ArrayList(set)` is similar to `list = new ArrayList()` and then `list.addAll(set)`.

Answer (score 5):

Use Java 8 features:

```
Set<Set<Integer>> data = new HashSet<>();

List<List<Integer>> result = data.stream()
                                 .map(ArrayList::new)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Example:

```
Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
set1.add(1);
set1.add(2);
set1.add(3);

Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>();
set2.add(4);
set2.add(5);
set2.add(6);

data.add(set1);
data.add(set2);

List<List<Integer>> result = data.stream()
                                 .map(ArrayList::new)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

printing result:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] // list of lists
```